# Class referenced in the manifest was not found in the project or the libraries

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

Recently I tried to remove all lint issues and in the manifest appeared an issue : 
"Class referenced in the manifest, com.octo.android.robospice.JacksonSpringAndroidSpiceService, was not found in the project or the libraries"

```
    <service
        android:name="com.octo.android.robospice.JacksonSpringAndroidSpiceService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
```

This is a maven dependency and is also included in the build.gradle file :

```
dependencies {
  ...
    compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice:1.4.11'
    compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-spring-android:1.4.11'
   ...
}
```

What else could be done to resolve this lint warning or do I have to suppress it?

Answer (score 19):

In my case I forgot to add the package on top in kotlin file

```
package com.user.examplephone;
```

Comment: In my case the package was wrong because I renamed and moved a file around.

Answer (score 11):

go to file->Invalidate cashes and restart

it works for me

Answer (score 5):

I know it's an old question but I ran into a similar issue today. The problem was in the name of the service. If you had the class in your project, then the name should be:

```
  <service
        android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE.YOUR_CLASS_NAME"
        android:exported="false" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.OssLicensesActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/LicensesTheme"
            tools:ignore="MissingClass"/>
```

You need to add

```
tools:ignore="MissingClass"
```

Comment: That helped to remove the error.. However functions from the class are not called :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after scrubbing SO for solutions to this.  I finally put the fully qualified path name to MainActivity in my manifest, and Invalidated caches, and restarted.  Worked for me. YMMV

Comment: how to find a proper path for MainActivity in the manifest?